# Remove similar (not duplicate) time stamps from the data in R

Tags: r, timestamp

I have a dataframe with two columns i.e. time stamps and magnitude. The data looks like as follows:

```
time stamps                     Magnitude
"2010-04-2 19:58:39 CEST"          1
"2010-04-2 19:58:49 CEST"          2
"2010-04-2 19:58:59 CEST"          3
"2010-04-2 19:59:09 CEST"          4
"2010-04-2 19:59:19 CEST"          5 

"2010-04-2 19:58:40 CEST"          1
"2010-04-2 19:58:50 CEST"          2
"2010-04-2 19:58:60 CEST"          3
"2010-04-2 19:59:70 CEST"          4
"2010-04-2 19:59:80 CEST"          5
```

I want to remove these similar time stamps which are not duplicate of each other. I have tried subsetting  based on duplicate rows but obviously that will not work.

Comment: I don't see any duplicate `timestamps` in the example you have provided. What is your expected output?

Comment: Yeah that is the point, i want to remove similar time stamps i.e. only one of the time stamps "2010-04-2 19:58:39 CEST" and "2010-04-2 19:58:40 CEST" should be retained in data

Comment: How do you define "similarity" ? Matching only the last digit?

Comment: @Gujj You need to define what you mean by "similar time stamps". Time stamps that are 1 second apart? 2 seconds? 10 seconds?

Comment: The time stamps match at the level of hours in the timestamps

Comment: @Gujj *"match at the level of hours"* Are you sure you mean hours? That would collapse your sample data into a single row. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using `lubridate`. I'll assume you want to remove entries that are duplicated at the level of date-hour-minute, i.e. not considering seconds.

```
library(lubridate)
df[!duplicated(floor_date(df$timestamps, unit = "minute")), ]
#           timestamps Magnitude
#1 2010-04-02 19:58:39         1
#4 2010-04-02 19:59:09         4
```

Change the unit to `hour` or whatever you need.